# Passing an object that undergoes default argument promotion to 'va_start'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

This is my first Xcode app and objective-c so give me some slack :)

I tried googling on the issue but I cannot see any help regarding Xcode and app development. I added the error masseages after //

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(int8_t)byte1, ... { //Error: 1. Parameter of type 'int8_t' (aka 'signed char') is declared here
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, byte1); //Error: Passing an object that undergoes default argument promotion to 'va_start' has undefined behavior
  unsigned int length = 0;
  for (int8_t byte = byte1; byte != -1; byte = va_arg(args, int)) {
    length++;
  }
  va_end(args);

  if ((self = [self initWithLength:length]) && (length > 0)) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, byte1); // Error: Passing an object that undergoes default argument promotion to 'va_start' has undefined behavior
    int i = 0;
    for (int8_t byte = byte1; byte != -1; byte = va_arg(args, int)) {
      _array[i++] = byte;
    }
    va_end(args);
  }
 return self;
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Wow that is complicated.  Why not pass a array of `uint8_t`s and a length?

Comment: @trojanfoe Wish I knew how :) I'm too new to understand what my code does.

Comment: Well varargs are rarely used.  You will generally only see them used for logging/printing (see `NSLog()` and `printf()`) so throw them away.  If you want to pass an array of characters/bytes then pass a pointer and a length and that is enough to describe the array.  For example: `- (nonnull instancetype)initWithBuffer:(const uint_t *)buffer ofLength:(NSUInteger)length { ... };`. In fact that's pretty much what the `NSData` class does anyway, so you probably should be using that instead.  Show the class declaration and I'll provide a proper answer.

Comment: I don't know why `va_start` doesn't like `int8_t`, try use other type. Btw what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried a few options to `int8_t`but still errors. Which one do you propose I use? @Cy-4AH

Comment: Try Just `Int`.

Answer (score 4):

`va_start()` saves the pointer to the first argument passed to the function into a `va_list`.
The arguments themselves are passed via a hardware stack.

The issue with int8_t comes from the way the hardware stack is implemented. (in x86 at least)

Just like the SSE and MMX does, the stack requires elements stored on it to have an alignment equal to a multiple of 16bits, so everything passed to the function WILL have at least 16 bits of size, regardless of its type.

But the problem is `va_arg()` doesn't know about all that. Historically, it was a macro, and all it does is returning a pointer stored in `va_list`, and incrementing `va_list` by `sizeof(type)`.

So, when you retrieve the next argument, the pointer returned does not point to the next argument but one byte before it, or not - depending on whether the `va_arg` is a macro or a compiler built-in function.

And this is what a warning is about.

IMO at least. Pardon my English, It's my 2nd language.

Comment: I don't know anything about objective-C, but this answer sounds right to me.  Here are some more detailed examples from C/C++ that support the point.
https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP58-CPP.+Pass+an+object+of+the+correct+type+to+va_start